# Linking Combo box item to a web page in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm working on this win8 app that includes a combo box. The combo box contains a list of topics and when a single topic is clicked, it opens up a webpage. Not in a browser but in a WebView. I've tried doing it with switch and this what I came up with. But I get an error on the MainPage.xaml that says that:

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Reader.MainPage.ComboBox_selectionChanged(object, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type

I'd prefer not to have to use a button. I've looked into binding but I don't understand how it works very well. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

```
private async Task ComboBox_selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (selectUrl.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    await GetFeeds("http://...");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    await GetFeeds("http://...");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    await GetFeeds("http://...");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    await GetFeeds("http://...");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    await GetFeeds("http://...");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for Combo_Box you have to set the return type to 'void' or other problem can be with how u get the selected item . try getting it into variable of type 'ComboBox' as below

```
  private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ComboBoxItem item = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;


    }
```

Comment: Do I bind the combo box item to the url in this manner? Can you please explain more? Thank you.

Comment: I didnt try coding it btw did changing return type to void worked ? and this way u will get the binded value instead of index number .